# I need help understanding why am I am not getting any results with below query

Tags: sql, oracle

Using query #1 below I get the the following results

```
select DATE, count (DATE) from TABLE1
group by DATE
```

| DATE | COUNT(DATE) |
| --- | --- |
| 6/6/2022 | 6856 |
| 6/6/2022 2:06:10 PM | 78895 |
| 6/6/2022 2:06:11 PM | 90230 |
| 6/6/2022 2:06:12 PM | 95693 |
| 6/6/2022 2:06:13 PM | 94352 |
| 6/6/2022 2:06:14 PM | 9101 |
| 6/27/2022 | 6854 |
| 6/27/2022 7:36:58 PM | 6422 |

Using the above results, I am now trying to write a query which will only isolate the 6/27/2022 dates, which are the two line items at the bottom of my results. I've tried using a `to_char` function as well as `Like` function but all variations of the queries that I write result in "No Records". In other words, the query runs but I get no results.

```
Select * from TABLE where to_char(DATE) like '%06/27/2022%'
```

Can someone help me with this.

Thank you,

Comment: `where date >= '2022-06-27' and date < '2022-06-28'`. This is assuming your schema uses the correct data type datetime or datetime2 (or something similar). If you want more help please tag the RDBMS you are using (like sql server, mysql, oracle, etc).

Comment: @Igor's search criteria is definitively better.

Comment: @Igor thank you for the response, unfortunately I get an oracle error message "ORA-01843: not a valid month". Also FYI, the field data type is DATE

Comment: Based on that error message this is Oracle. This is why it is important to always tag the RDBMS in your question because of syntax differences. `WHERE date >= TO_DATE('2022-06-27', 'yyyy-MM-dd') and date < TO_DATE('2022-06-28', 'yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: Your field data type can't be `DATE` as long as it contains time values too. Also it doesn't resemble a standard `DATETIME` data type (unless you have changed the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` global variable). Are you sure you have not declared it with the `VARCHAR` type?

Comment: @lemon, based on the schema browser data and data_type for this specific field in this particular table it specifically states that the data type is DATE.

Comment: You can't because the format is constant for every SQL statement. But you can use a query like @Igor for your result.

Comment: @Igor, thank you, the To_DATE function worked.

Comment: @lemon Oracle's `date` is a misleading name for `datetime`, so it always contain time component with the seconds precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column is a `DATE` data type and you want all the values from one day then:

```sql
Select *
from   table_name
where  date_column >= DATE '2022-06-28'
and    date_column <  DATE '2022-06-29'
```

If you want all the values at a particular instant then:

```sql
Select *
from   table_name
where  date_column = DATE '2022-06-28' + INTERVAL '14:06:10' HOUR TO SECOND
```

or

```sql
Select *
from   table_name
where  date_column = TIMESTAMP '2022-06-28 14:06:10';
```

or

```sql
Select *
from   table_name
where  TO_CHAR(date_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = '2022-06-28 14:06:10';
```

---

If your column is a string data type then use the `TO_DATE` function to convert it to a date data type and then use one of the queries above.

For example:

```sql
Select *
from   table_name
where  TO_DATE(string_column, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') >= DATE '2022-06-28'
and    TO_DATE(string_column, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') <  DATE '2022-06-29'
```